# How to protect excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement where I want to make Excel sheet protected. Below steps are involved:

1. I have a VBA macro code written in excel
2. When user clicks button it creates report and park it at given path
3. This report file is excel file
4. We want to make this report file password protected when it is getting generated using VBA code

Pls suggest some solution.

Comment: You can also consider either hiding the sheet or using vba going to “very hidden” - you can still get the hidden sheet to calculate etc.

Comment: What is your question? And what did you try so far? Please read [ask] and [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim ws as worksheet
for each ws in worksheets
ws.protect password:="sid"
next ws
Activeworkbook.protect password:="fred"
```